# Computation of the likelihood of the following two questions with balls in urns

Tags: probability, solution-verification, bayes-theorem

> Urn A contains three balls: one black, and two white; urn B contains
> three balls: two black, and one white. One of the urns is selected at
> random and one ball is drawn. The ball is black. What is the
> probability that the selected urn is urn A?

For the above problem I solved the following:

$p(U_a | B) = \frac{p(B|U_a)P(U_a)}{P(B)}$

with $P(B) = \sum_{U} p(B|U_a)P(U_a) + P(B|U_B)P(U_B) = 2/3 \times 0.5 + 1/3 \times 0.5 = 0.5$

So $p(U_a | B) = \frac{1/3 \times 0.5}{0.5} = \frac{1}{3}$

Anyone can confirm if this is in fact right?

Similarly for the second problem below I used the same method

> Urn A contains five balls: one black, two white, one green and  one
> pink; urn B contains five hundred balls: two hundred black, one
> hundred white, 50 yellow, 40 cyan, 30 sienna, 25 green, 25 silver, 20
> gold, and 10 purple. [One fifth of A’s balls are black; two-fifths of
> B’s are black. One of the urns is selected at random and one ball is
> drawn. The ball is black. What is the probability that the urn is urn
> A?

$P(U_a|B) = \frac{0.2 * 0.5}{(0.2 \times 0.5 + 0.4 \times 0.5} = \frac{1}{3}$

More unsure of the second answer but would love it if someone could confirm my thinking, thanks

Comment: Your answer is correct (at least the reasoning and formula, I didn't check the algebra of the final answer), why are you more unsure of the second answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did fine.

For the first problem there is a more direct solution that avoids the use of the rule of Bayes.

---

Since both urns have the same number of balls and secondly the choosing of the urn is at random we can conclude that all balls have equal probability to be the drawn ball.

One of the black balls comes from urn A and two from urn B, so the probability that the drawn ball came from urn A equals $\frac13$.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. This was one of the few examples without a solution so i was keen to double check. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Both of your answers are correct (didn't check the algebra but the reasoning and formula are correct), as a rule of thumb whenever you have a partition of your sample space and a conditional probability you can/should Bayes' theorem.

Since your sample space is partitioned between two urns and you need to get the probability of drawing from a certain urn GIVEN the ball is black then Bayes' theorem is suitable here.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. This was one of the few examples without a solution so i was keen to double check. Thanks again